# Use UINavigationController inside UITabbarController

Tags: ios, xcode, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, swift4.2

I'm trying to Use UINavigationController inside a UITabbarController.

this is my Controllers Structure

```
-UITabbarController(InitialView)
  -tabItemOne-DashboardController
    -SomeButtons with StoryboardSegue-To-DifferentViewController
  -tabItemTwo-OtherController
  -tabItemThree-OtherController
```

[image: storyboardScreenShot]

[image]

Now I want to show the back button when some `StoryboardSegue` is performed in `DashboardViewController`.
Let's say I open the app and can see 4 tabbarItems on `UITabbarController`, in the first `tabbar item` I have `DashboardViewController`, in this DashVC I've 3 4 different buttons to show other viewcontrollers. So far so good, everything is working. but once the child viewcontroller from DashVC is on screen, I want to show a back button on the top as `UINavigationController` do.

I've tried to put the `UINavigationController` before `UITabbarController` but its not showing. i've tried to do `embed it in DashboardVC` but again its `not showing`.

Do i need to embed seperate `UINavigationController` with each of `childViewControllers` of `DashboardVC`?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I suppose, your segues have the wrong kind (push, modal, etc.)

Comment: i'm using Show(e.g. Push) from dashboard buttons to childviewcontrollers

Comment: Are you showing the same ViewController from other NavigationControllers ?

Comment: No.. the childviewControllers are directly segued to dashboard.. there is no segue or connectection to childviewcontrollers anywhere else

Comment: Could you please provide a screenshot of your storyboard?

Comment: @kirander please check now. i've added screenshot

Comment: @Joe - your storyboard screenshot doesn't show a tab-bar controller?

Comment: @DonMag the first viewcontroller on left is the tabbar controller.. i'm setting it programmatically in customclass.

Comment: @Joe - OK... your "Main Tab Bar Controller" needs to be your root VC. The ***Navigation Controller*** should be the first tab, with `DashVC ` as its root VC... any VC that you `push` from there (default "show" segue) will automatically show the Back button on the Nav Controller's navigation bar.

Comment: @DonMag, please check the second screenshot. and I'm doing it already just like you said.

Comment: @Joe - I suspect you're not getting something loaded correctly. This is how it would look if you connected everything in Storyboard: https://imgur.com/a/evGXXph

Comment: @DonMag, i've changed my storyboard to embed all my viewcontrollers using Embed In option. now its working.. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]So what you need is this

```
-UITabbarController(InitialView)
  -NavigationController -tabItemOne-DashboardController
    -SomeButtons with StoryboardSegue-To-DifferentViewController
  -tabItemTwo-OtherController
  -tabItemThree-OtherController
```

and in DashBoardController you need to add this code in

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isHidden = true
    }

    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isHidden = false
    }
```

this code is to hide the navigation bar in Dashboard and restoring when pushing another view controller so you back button is not hide.
also if you need the same functionality in the others view controller you should embebed in navigation controllers.

is not exactly your case but all navigation Controller are Childs of the UITabBarController that is the initial viewController.

Comment: yes, as you can see in screenshot this what I'm doing.. but the navigationcontroller isn't showing in childViewControllers... :(((( but let me double-check and see it works.

Comment: i don't see the Childs of the TabBarController the navigation controller should be a childviewcontroller of your UITabBarController, I'll post a pic how I should be

Comment: the first viewcontroller on left is the tabbar controller.. i'm setting it programmatically in customclass. and then adding all controllers through code.

Comment: why don't you do tha in storyBoard since you have all viewControllers there,

Comment: wanted to do some customization to UITabbarController so had to do it in code.. Please check the question again.. i've added how the segue appears in storyboard for childviewcontrollers

Comment: man you can do all the custom you want and still using in storyboard you just have to assign the class to the uiTabBarController in storyBoard, so  I do like adding a custom button and other things like custom transitions, etc, also post the code where you add the child to tababarController

Comment: thanks man.. I've switched to storyboard and now its showing, still some bugs in layout but atleast its showing something now.. but i'm pretty sure it should work even through code. I'll look into this coded version later.

Comment: but can i hide tabbar on childviewcontrollers? or they will stay there in all controllers? I've check facebook insta and some other apps with same behaviour but don't like it on all chilviewcontrollers.

Comment: yes man you chan do it search in here to see it, is simple but is another question. also is worked vote the answer